# Download pdf from downloadlink to my uploads folder PHP

Tags: php, pdf, curl

I'm trying to download invoices(loop) to my uploads folder so clients can download. I don't want to redirect. 
I've tried file get and put contents. Got empty pdfs. then  tried curl:

```
$ch = curl_init($pdfurl);
    $fp = fopen('../uploads/'. $invoice. '', 'wb');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

Doesnt seem to work.. the pdfurl is a download link, it doesnt show pdf, it prompts u to download.. that might be the problem?

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');

            // It will be called downloaded.pdf
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$invoice.pdf"');

            // The PDF source is in original.pdf
            readfile($pdfurl);
```

This works. but I want to move the pdfs from loop to upload folder.

Answer (score 0):

...problem solved.. was on development server.. thats why i couldnt open the pdfs..

```
file_put_contents("../uploads/".$factuurnummer. ".pdf", fopen($pdfurl, 'r'));
```